# Basic Java > can byte array function parameter by modified in a function call

Tags: java, arrays, function

According to my understanding, Java does not have pointer, so any function parameter can not be modified in a function call, say even a parameter value is modified inside a function call, but after the function call the parameter's value still keeps the previous value

Am I right?

Comment: Please provide some code examples to indicate what you mean. In doing so, you may likely discover the answer for yourself.

Comment: You would be right regarding primitive types, but not with object types e.g. If you pass a List to a method and that method adds to the list, then it will have that added value after you leave the method.

Comment: for instance, public void change(byte[] array), if this parameter array's values are changed during the functional call, is this array kept unchanged after the functional call?

Comment: @user1928863 There's nothing stopping you from trying. However the duplicate answers your question.

Comment: Where is the duplicate?

Comment: Try refreshing the page. The link should appear under the question title.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. 
Java only have `call by value` for function parameter. After function has finished execution, the parameter it used will no longer referenced by others.ie, garbage.